# nanogallery2 how to Open the popup slider images directly after clicking on album thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using nanogalley2 to show album galley on a web page. My question is How to Open the popup slider images directly after clicking on album thumbnail without moving to the second step which shows the album images themselves?

the script currently working in this way:
step 1- click on the album thumbnail.
step 2- show the album's images with back button and this button named with the album name.
step 3- after clicking on any image of the select album the slider images popup will shown.

What I need is to move to third step directly after clicking on the album thumbnail in the first step, which includes opening the slider images popup directly.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery("#my_nanogallery2").nanogallery2({
    items:[
      // album 1
      {
        src:   'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg',             // image url
        srct:  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg',         // thumbnail url
        title: 'Project Name', // item title
        ID: 1,                 // item ID
        kind: 'album',         // item kind
      },

      { src: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', srct: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', title: 'Video Title', ID: 10, albumID: 1},
      { src: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', srct: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', title: 'image Title', ID: 11, albumID: 1},
      { src: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', srct: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', title: 'image Title', ID: 12, albumID: 1},

    // album 2
    { 
      src:   'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg',           // image url
      srct:  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg',       // thumbnail url
      title: 'Project Name',   // item title

      ID: 2,
      kind: 'album'
    },
    {
       src: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', srct: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', title: 'Video Title', ID: 20, albumID: 2},
      { src: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', srct: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', title: 'image Title', ID: 21, albumID: 2},
      { src: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', srct: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', title: 'image Title', ID: 22, albumID: 2},
      { src: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', srct: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', title: 'image Title', ID: 23, albumID: 2},

      // album 3
      {
        src:   'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg',             // image url
        srct:  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg',         // thumbnail url
        title: 'Project Name',   // item title
        ID: 3,                   // item ID
        kind: 'album'            // item kind
      },
      { src: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', srct: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', title: 'Video Title', ID: 30, albumID: 3},
      { src: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', srct: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', title: 'image Title', ID: 31, albumID: 3},
      { src: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', srct: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', title: 'image Title', ID: 32, albumID: 3},
      { src: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', srct: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg', title: 'image Title', ID: 33, albumID: 3},
    ],

    thumbnailWidth:  'auto',
    thumbnailHeight: 170,
    itemsBaseURL:    'https://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/samples/',
    thumbnailHoverEffect2: null,
    locationHash:    false,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nanogallery2@3/dist/css/nanogallery2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nanogallery2@3/dist/jquery.nanogallery2.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="my_nanogallery2"></div>
```

Comment: Please add a description of your problem or error and formulate a question.

Comment: Please run code snippet to show the script result. I need to open the slider images directly after clicking on album thumbnail without moving to the second step which showing the album's images themselve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can use the option `thumbnailAlbumDisplayImage`.
Simply set it to `true`.

This option is no more described in the library's documentation (maybe a bad manipulation): this has been fixed.